# import errors after installing vtk

Tags: homebrew, vtk

I used brew to install vtk. When I try to import vtk in Python, I get `ImportError: No module named vtkIOImagePython`

I'm assuming something is maybe wrong with my paths, but I can't figure it out.

Thanks!